# $2310 $ points are evenly marked on circle.How many regular polygons can be drawn by joining some of these points.

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:-** $2310$ points are evenly marked on circle.How many regular polygons can be drawn by joining some of these points(**$N$ -sided polygon should be counted only once**).

I came across this question in my assignment.I wasn't able to solve this question since I don't know method to tackle such kind of problems involving polygons.Can somebody tell me what is the method to solve this problem!

Thank you for your help!!
$
$
$
$

Comment: *Hint*: reformulate the question to only involving numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

What is a number of all divisors of 2310?

If $m = p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2}... p_k^{n_k}$ then the number of all divisors is:

$$(n_1+1)(n_2+1)...(n_k+1)$$

Comment: I guess there are no $1$-gon and no $2$-gon.

Comment: Answer is 30 now I got it.

Comment: @Paras The number of divisors (minus $2$) counts the possible $N$ for which regular $N$-gons exist, it does not count regular $N$-gons.

Answer (score 2):

The prime factorization of $2310$ is $2310=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11$. For each divisor $d\mid2310$, $d>=3$, we can find $\frac{2310}{d}$ regular $d$-gons on that circle, so we have to find the sum of the divisors $d\mid2310$ except those with $d>\frac{2310}{3}$ ($2310$ and $1155$). The sum of all divisors of $2310$ can be factorized as $(2+1)(3+1)(5+1)(7+1)(11+1)$, but we have to subtract the $2310$ $1$-gons and the $1155$ (diametral) $2$-gons, so the total number of regular polygons we can find on that circle is
$$
3\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot12-2310-1155=3447
$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with that factorisaton. How you get it?

Comment: @Aqua: Doing the multiplications to remove the parentheses, you will reveive the sum of the integers that are divisible only by the prime numbers $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$ and/or $11$, each with a multiplcity of either $0$ or $1$. These are the divisors of $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11=2310$.

Comment: I think you've made an error on the factorisation, it should be `(1+1)^5 = 32`. then we handle those edge cases you mentioned and it becomes `30`.

Comment: @Elliott $32$ is the **number** of divisors, but we were interested in their **sum**.

Comment: @WolfgangKais, I'm not sure why we'd be interested in any sum here (although I'm not sure what your sum is counting?) But as a sanity check, if we look back to the OP `How many regular polygons can be drawn by joining some of these points( -sided polygon should be counted only once)`, so an obvious deduction is that the answer should be less than `2310`.

Comment: @Elliott You are counting the possible $N$ for which regular $N$-gons exist, I am counting the distinct $N$-gons for each possible $N$ as the OP asked with "How many regular polygons...". For example, if we have $6$ points evenly marked on a circle and numbered clockwise from $1$ to $6$, we have two distinct regular triangles: $\{1, 3, 5\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6\}$, and also we have the regular $6$-gon $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.